# SQL union all performance when finding differences between two tables

Tags: sql, performance, db2, compare, union-all

I'm trying  to compare two databases and extract rows from files where there are any differences in individual files that exist in both. The two files may not have the same number of columns but they will have the same key fields.

First I find the file name common to both, the fields common to both and key fields common to both.

Here is the SQL I'm then using for the compare for an example file XXPF found in LIB1 and LIB2 with 4 common fields XXFLD1 - 4.

```
INSERT INTO COMPARE.XXPF 
SELECT MIN(file) AS file,XXFLD1, XXFLD2, XXFLD3, XXFLD4 
FROM (  SELECT 'LIB1' AS file, XXFLD1, XXFLD2, XXFLD3, XXFLD4 FROM LIB1.XXPF A  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT 'LIB2' AS file, XXFLD1, XXFLD2, XXFLD3, XXFLD4 FROM LIB2.XXPF B  ) tmp
GROUP BY XXFLD1, XXFLD2, XXFLD3, XXFLD4
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This works fine but for large files with many more fields and hundreds of thousands or millions of records it is very slow.  I can see from the visual explain it is doing a full table scan on both files, creating another table and then doing the selection from there.

Now considering I know XXFLD1 and XXFLD2 are keys to both these files is there a better construction that will get me the same results more efficiently?  That is the rows (or just fields) that are different between the two libraries for a given key value.  I'm using DB2 on IBM i

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why not do a full outer join between the two tables using those key fields, and look for where one side of the query is all-nulls.

Comment: Will this give me records only in LIB1 or only in LIB2 as well as differences?

Comment: What I mean is if key fields are first name, last name, FLD3 is address and FLD4 is account balance then I want to know if JOHN SMITH has a different account balance or address in the two libraries or if JACK SMITH only exists in LIB1 or only exists in LIB2